# A shorcut for compiling and executing code in kate?

Tags: shortcut-keys, compiling, configuration, kate

I am writing some Fortran code in Kate. Currently every time I do a change to the code I have to save it, then in the built-in terminal type `gfortran "file name goes here" && ./a.out`, where `gfortran` compiles the code and `a.out` is the executable.

I would like to configure Kate so that it can save the script, compile and execute the code using a shortcut key or a toolbar icon, and display the output in the built-in terminal. Is that possible?

Comment: Close voters:  Kate is available in the Ubuntu repositories, and simple an editor for programming.

Comment: I have had very little experience with Fortran since the '80s...  Kate seems to have poor maintenance at this time.  [this article](http://www.tuxmachines.org/node/13762) explains the use of a plugin, but [this later article](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/37766/how-can-i-run-my-own-scripts-in-kate-3-8-2-external-tools-isnt-available-in) explains the plugin was unmaintained and dropped....